# How to set the Jinja environment variable in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a page with the following Code Structure:

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("first.html")

@app.route('/second')
def next():
    return render_template("second.html")

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML Code for second.html:

```
{% extends first.html %}
<dosomething>
</dosomething>
```

Now I want to set the Environment of Jinja as follows:

Environment:

```
import jinja2

JINJA_ENV=jinja2.Environment(block_start_string='#%',block_end_string="#%",variable_start_string='{',variable_end_string='}')
```

I want this changes to be reflected in Flask. Should this variable be initialized with Flask in some way or left as such?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62972607/1662230

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not publically documented, but a `Flask()` object has a `.jinja_options` dict that will be used to build the Jinja Environment. Just make sure to set it ASAP.

Source:

https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/bbb273bb761461ab329f03ff2d9002f6cb81e2a4/src/flask/app.py#L272

https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/bbb273bb761461ab329f03ff2d9002f6cb81e2a4/src/flask/app.py#L652

Example:

```
from flask import Flask
from jinja2 import ChainableUndefined

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_options["undefined"] = ChainableUndefined
```

Comment: Thanks. It is documented here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.jinja_options.

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass in an entire Jinja Environment like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from jinja2 import Environment

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env = Environment(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

The current version of Flask doesn't allow you to modify `app.jinja_options` after your create your `app`, so you need to set your own `Environment` instance instead.

If you just want to modify Flask's Jinja defaults instead of creating your own environment, you can subclass `Environment` and just override the options you want to modify:

```py
from flask.templating import Environment

app = Flask(__name__)

class CustomEnvironment(Environment):
    def __init__(self, app, **options):
        options['lstrip_blocks'] = True # override default option 
        super().__init__(app, **options)

app.jinja_env = CustomEnvironment(app)
```

There's a [list of available options](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.Environment) in the Jinja docs.