# How to enable/configure Jinja line statements in Flask 1.0.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

The [Jinja documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#line-statements) states the following regarding line statements:

> If line statements are enabled by the application, it’s possible to mark a line as a statement.

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48SzkMnqJ3c&t=161s) video, line statements are enabled/configured like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.line_statement_prefix = '%'
```

However, in Flask 1.0.4 my application object does not have this attribute.

How can I enable and configure line statements?

Comment: I think you'll need to update jinja2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to the source, `app.jinja_env` is a `locked_cached_property` which is created the first time it is accessed. So we can't set options directly on `app.jinja_env`.

What we can do is set `app.jinja_options` when we are creating our app so that when jinja goes to load the environment it looks at the default `app.jinja_options` in Flask already which are

```
jinja_options = {"extensions": ["jinja2.ext.autoescape", "jinja2.ext.with_"]}
```

So with that, I believe the following should do what we need

```
from flask import Flask

Flask.jinja_options = {'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.autoescape', 'jinja2.ext.with_'], 'line_statement_prefix': '%'}
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Flask breaks up the options object, passes that to the Environment which is a subclass of Jinja Environment which then assigns the line_statement_prefix.

Comment: Updating `jinja_options` after `app` is created is not possible in version 1.0.4, since it is an immutable dict. However, setting them in the `Flask` class before instantiation works fine. `Flask.jinja_options = {'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.autoescape', 'jinja2.ext.with_'], 'line_statement_prefix': '%'}` first, then: `app = Flask(__name__)`. Thanks for your tip. Please edit your answer, so I can mark it as the solution for others

Comment: @zwithouta I have updated my post to reflect changes you have suggested

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Flask 3.0. It also doesn't seem like a good idea to hard code Flask's defaults, since they may change in future releases. Maybe there's a way to dynamically load the default options. Otherwise, subclassing Flask's `templating.Environment` class (a subclass of Jinja's `Environment`) and overriding the `options` there is a way to safely to set just the `line_statement_prefix` option.