# jinja2-humanize-extension - how to implement these into code?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I would like to use the humanize functions in my jinja2 flask app and the example from the documentation was too vague for me. I installed the extensions with pip and tried to implement them as follows:

What I would like to render is this:

```
<small class="text-muted">Time remaining: {{ ((submission.date_expiration - now)|naturaldelta()) }}</small>
```

Although I keep getting the error: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: No filter named 'naturaldelta'.`

I added `env = Environment(extensions=["jinja2_humanize_extension.HumanizeExtension"])` to my *init*.py but realized this isn't adding the extensions properly. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: see https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/templating-with-jinja2-in-flask-advanced--cms-25794 about creating a custom context and filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you're getting that error when calling `render_template` from within your Flask app.  I note that the [full example](https://github.com/metwork-framework/jinja2_humanize_extension#full-example) in the extension's docs, only mentions rendering with `env.from_string`.

How to register this on a normal Flask app?  Seems you can set `app.jinja_options` once you've defined the app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_options['extensions'] = ['jinja2_humanize_extension.HumanizeExtension']
```

---

**I'm not actually sure if the above approach is "correct".  I'd looked around for documentation on how to register a Jinja2 env on a Flask app, but couldn't find much.  Here's how I did test this...**

With some clues from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151238/how-to-set-the-jinja-environment-variable-in-flask) your Flask app should have an attribute `app.jinja_options`, which in my case with a fresh app was is empty dictionary:

```
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>> app.jinja_options
{}
```

So I add the extension with:

```
>>> app.jinja_options['extensions'] = ['jinja2_humanize_extension.HumanizeExtension']
```

Then verify:

```
>>> app.jinja_options
{'extensions': ['jinja2_humanize_extension.HumanizeExtension']}
```

Then test at the terminal with Flask's `render_template_string`:

```
>>> from flask import render_template_string
>>> with app.app_context(): 
...  print( render_template_string('''{{300000|humanize_naturalsize()}}''', asd='abc'))
... 
300.0 kB
```

This should have the same effect when you're template is rendered as standard with `render_template`

Comment: Hey v25, thanks so much for the in depth response! I also struggled to find documentation on registering the Jinja2 environment in Flask. How is this then related to the render_template_string? 

Regarding the env.from_string, I don't quite understand what that is doing. Do you mind explaining a little? Does that mean that these extension functions cannot be directly implemented in the HTML file?

I am curious if I can then use these functions in my HTML code (for example in the line shown in the post) as normal after adding the extension as you described. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The example in the humanize docs uses `env.from_string` to return a template which can then be rendered with `template.render`.  I think this example assumes that you're just using Jinja2 directly (Jinja2 is a module which is *used by flask*, but can also be *used alone*).  The approach in my answer works with Flask, where you don't typically have direct access to the `env` instance in any case, and you would just use `render_template` (Although you didn't state *how* you were rendering your template - you only showed the HTML template code).

Comment: As for `render_template_string` this is just a Flask function which takes a string instead of the path to an HTML file, which is useful for trying stuff out in the console (within the `with app.app_context` block), as I have in my answer: It saves me having to write template code to a file, then call `render_template` with that path.  BUT yes the apprach in my answer should also be compatible with "your HTML code".  Please try this out, and consider marking this answer accepted if this works) :)  Hope these comments clear some stuff up.

Comment: Thanks for those explanations :) I'm gonna test it out and will let you know!

Comment: I have it working in the terminal like you showed but am still getting the same error with my render_template. I am assuming that I didn't properly add it to the app.jinja_options in my code. 

Here is my code:
`from flask import Flask
app = Flask (__name__)
app.jinja_options['extensions'] = ['jinja2_humanize_extension.HumanizeExtension']

@app.route("/submissions", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def submissions():
...
return render_template("curate.html", title="Curate", submission_count=submission_count, submissions=submissions, now=now)`

Comment: In the HTML code the filter needs `humanize_` before the name of the filter.  Try with `{{ ((submission.date_expiration - now)|humanize_naturaldelta()) }}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236619/discussion-between-danieljerrehian-and-v25).